# VB6 Datagrid update manually

Tags: datagrid, vb6

I would like to update data to Datagrid in Visual basic 6 manually by accessing [row,column] (Without connecting to database), How to do it?

If I summarize further, How to add the data without connecting to database?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313330

Comment: I love the offline-recordset, it is maybe one of the most useful objects in all of vb(a).